# jQuery instead of Mootools in Joomla 1.6

Tags: jquery, joomla, mootools, frontend, joomla1.6

Am am using both jQuery and Mootools on my Joomla frontend. Is there eny simple way to get rid of Mootools without editing Joomla core files, this is what i've been doing but I dont want that temprorary solution any more.

Comment: As Colum mentioned, you might consider picking up Mootools. You can never completely remove it because it is required for the back end and there are many extensions that use it on the front end. Virtuemart in particular is one that is nearly impossible to get Mootools out of.

Comment: If he/she doesn't need it, why should one keep somenthing that only takes users and hosting transfer, besides It shows that a website is running on Joomla and reveals Joomla version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In template's **index.php**:

```
$user     =& JFactory::getUser();
$app      =& JFactory::getApplication();

// Keep MooTools on the back-end 
if ( $app->isSite() ) {

  $prohibited = array (
        '/media/system/js/core.js',
        '/media/system/js/mootools-core.js',
        '/media/system/js/mootools-more.js',
        '/media/system/js/caption.js'
        );

 foreach ($this->_scripts as $key => $value) {
  if( in_array($key, $prohibited ) ) {
        unset($this->_scripts[$key]);
  }
 }
}
```

There are plugins, but despite the fact you will install another 3rd party plugin, you should know that if some Mootools script is added to Joomla in the future you will have to wait for the plugin to be updated. With this code you have better control, because all what you need to do is add the URI of the new script to the **'$prohibited'** array.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of doing this.

1. There is a plugin, which I found [here](http://www.cocut.cn/jstuff/jextension/3943-remove-mootools-joomla-plugin.html)
2. You can edit the core files, which you said you do not want to do. (I found a guide on how to do it [here](http://www.webeks.net/joomla/remove-mootools-in-joomla-16.html))

But why not use MooTools? It has almost all the plugins you could find with jQuery, and the code it about the same (not to mention it is more powerful)